# Bootstrap 4 -> poner orden correcto de divs en html

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4, div

estoy trabajando con bootstrap y necesito ayuda sobre como posicionar correctamente el siguiente html, en función de como redimensione la pantalla según la foto (extra largo, largo, mediano, small y extra small).

(stack no me permite mostrar mi código html con los correspondientes divs)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## cajasAzules a {

```
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 1px solid blue;
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
```

}

## cajasVerdes a {

```
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50px solid green;
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  margin: 3px;
  text-decoration: none;
```

}

1
2
3
4
5
6

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

2
     2
     3

Comment: Y hasta ahora qué has intentando? Podrías mostrarnos esa configuración en tu CSS

Answer (score 0):

Si no quieres perder mucho tiempo, y es para una cosa rápida...
Haría digamos dos contenedores. Uno es el LG y XL, y el resto en otro. Y juegas ocultando uno u otro depende de la resolución.
Te pongo el del resto

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bgBlue"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bgBlue"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bgBlue"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bgBlue"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bgBlue"></div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 bgBlue"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem autem voluptatibus nihil perspiciatis quae, assumenda eaque eum. Quam alias explicabo accusamus nam velit recusandae tempore temporibus. At a voluptates laborum?
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 bgGreen"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 bgGreen"></div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 bgGreen"></div>
</div>
```